# Vector based video coding, could it match the latest hybrid coders?

Tags: video-compression

I could not find any image/video/media coding stackexchange so I thought that maybe this one would be the best fit.

It seems to me that the state of the art in video coding is constantly being pushed forward in terms of bigger macroblocks, more sophisticated hybrid coding control circuitry, more and more post- & pre- processing filters ( example deblocking filters ) and more modes of operation for basically everything in the machinery of ever growing complexity.

Does there exist any vector based coding technique which is anywhere near being able to compete with the latest hybrid coding technique standards like h265, VP9 et.c.

What do you think are the main reasons for why vector based video codecs aren't being investigated to a larger extent?

Personally I think it is because of too much work involved in developing a whole new framework where it is easier to just go on with more advanced variations of an already proven concept.

Comment: What do you mean by **vector based** video coding? Something using vector quantization ?

Comment: @Fat32 : I don't primarily have vector quantization in mind but rather "vector coding" in the same sense as "vector graphics" as opposed to "bitmap graphics" which any (for example transform) coding of still image bitmaps could be considered to be.